# Which users have the highest reputation without posting any answers?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions

I searched before, but I didn't find any solution. I just like to know a list of users who have the most reputation but **only from asking questions**.

Comment: so, you want to find it network wide?

Comment: @sagar, Specially in StackOverFlow.

Comment: @DamithRuwan _"... but **only from asking questions**?"_ So users with zero answers at all?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ May bezero answers, or answers without any up votes or accepted.

Comment: Have you had a go at finding out yourself? https://data.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/688618) for that:

[image]

[This user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/128983) has no answers but 37k reputation (though they might have gained reputation from suggested edits and/or the association bonus as well).

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 u.Id AS [User Link], u.Reputation
  FROM Users AS u
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Posts AS p
    ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
    AND p.PostTypeId = 2 -- answers
  WHERE p.Id IS NULL
  ORDER BY u.Reputation DESC
```

Comment: Luckily, [that particular user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128983/hap497?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) has not gained any rep from suggested edits.

Comment: That user asked last question in 2014. What happen to that guy? He could have easily get 100k rep if he asked question until now. However I like to meet that guy :-D